# Swagger2 is not detecting changes in the backend code

Tags: swagger-2.0

## dependencies

- springfox-swagger2: 2.9.2
- swagger-bootstrap-ui: 1.9.6

## issue description

I modified the backend code, but the Swagger2 API documentation still displays the old code information. I've tried commands like 'clean and install' and also attempted to clear the browser cache, reimport the project, but none of them have been effective. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Try again with; in Firefox Ctrl+Shift+R. And in IntelliJ IDEA File -> Invalidate Caches...

Comment: Thank you. Actually, it was my own oversight. The 'value' attribute of the 'ApiMode' annotation was duplicated, which caused this issue.I'm really being so foolish.